# SQL How to convert number to text with minimum decimal places (dynamic number of decimal places) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In an SQL query, I want to convert numeric value to text with minimum no. of decimal places, example if the number is 2.50, then I want output as 2.5; if number is 3, then I want output as 3; if number is 18.75, I want output as 18.75, etc.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT 1:
To give more background, I am dividing 2 numeric values, and want the result in text with minimum required decimal places.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 5):

In SQL 2012 and above you can write

```
SELECT FORMAT(15.0/4.0 , '#.########' )
```

It uses [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function which uses .NET [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) functionality.

Comment: Better to use `FORMAT(Field, '0.########' ), otherwise zero appears as the empty string, and decimals less than 1 appear without a leading zero (which is less of a problem).

Answer (score 0):

If want to get 2 decimals for division values, use this

```
 Select  case when right(cast ( x/y as decimal(18,2)),1) = 0 
              then left (cast ( x/y as decimal(18,2)),3) 
              else cast ( x/y as decimal(18,2)) end ReqOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    SomeNumber DECIMAL(9,7) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (SomeNumber) VALUES 
    (1.2345670), (1), (99.00100), (5.55);


SELECT 
    td.SomeNumber,
    REVERSE(STUFF(rcv.RevCastVarchar, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0.]%', rcv.RevCastVarchar) - 1, ''))
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (REVERSE(CAST(td.SomeNumber AS VARCHAR(10)))) ) rcv (RevCastVarchar);
```

HTH,
Jason